# How to use stringr and regex to convert strings(change, keep, extract) with some exceptions?

Tags: r, regex, stringr

Hey I have a dataset and I hand picked the following 7 entries as an example:

```
mydf <- data.frame(transmission = c('Auto(L3)','Auto(L4)','Auto (S4)','Automatic (6-spd)','Automatic (L3)',
'Automatic (variable gear ratios)', 'Manual 4-spd'))
```

which is

```
                      transmission
1                         Auto(L3)
2                         Auto(L4)
3                        Auto (S4)
4                  Automatic 6-spd
5                   Automatic (L3)
6 Automatic (variable gear ratios)
7                     Manual 4-spd
```

The requirement is to convert Auto(...) to Automatic ... - like Auto(L3) to Automatic L3, Auto (S4) to Automatic S4 - and to remove '(', ')','-', or ' ' except first blank space after Manual or Automatic - like Automatic (6-spd) to Automatic 6spd.

The result should yiedl:

```
                      transmission
1                     Automatic L3
2                     Automatic L4
3                     Automatic S4
4                   Automatic 6spd
5                     Automatic L3
6     Automatic variablegearratios
7                      Manual 4spd
```

Currently I'm using probably the dumbest way:

```
transmission %>% 
  str_replace_all(' \\(',' ') %>%
  str_replace_all('Auto ','Automatic ') %>%
  str_replace_all(' ','') %>%
  str_replace_all('[()-]','') %>%
  str_replace_all('Automatic','Automatic ') %>%
  str_replace_all('Manual','Manual ')
```

But it's so redundantly unnecessary and time-consuming.
What's the right and straightforward way to do it with stringr package(str_xxx functions) and regular expression?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
> mydf
                      transmission
1                         Auto(L3)
2                         Auto(L4)
3                        Auto (S4)
4                Automatic (6-spd)
5                   Automatic (L3)
6 Automatic (variable gear ratios)
7                     Manual 4-spd

> mydf$transmission_r = str_replace(mydf$transmission, "Auto(?:matic)?\\s?\\((.*)\\)", "Automatic \\1")
> mydf$transmission_r = str_replace_all(mydf$transmission_r, "-", "")
> mydf$transmission_r = str_replace_all(mydf$transmission_r, "(?<!Automatic|Manual)\\s", "")
> mydf
                      transmission                 transmission_r
1                         Auto(L3)                   Automatic L3
2                         Auto(L4)                   Automatic L4
3                        Auto (S4)                   Automatic S4
4                Automatic (6-spd)                 Automatic 6spd
5                   Automatic (L3)                   Automatic L3
6 Automatic (variable gear ratios)   Automatic variablegearratios
7                     Manual 4-spd                    Manual 4spd
```

## Explanation

Start with the word "Auto", then, using a non-matching group (using `?:`), indicate that "matic" might be present (using `(matic)?`). Next, indicate that a space might be present (`\\s?`). Next, escape the opening parenthesis (`\\(`), capture all of the text inside in a matching group (`(.*)`), and finally escape the closing parenthesis (`\\(`). This is our regular expression. We then replace it with the word "Automatic" followed by whatever was captured in our first matching group (`\\1`), which is whatever is inside of the parentheses.

Removing the hyphens is now just using `str_replace_all` to remove hyphens, and to remove all spaces except those between "Manual" or "Automatic" is just we use a negative look behind to ensure that the space is not preceded by those words (using `(?<!Automatic|Manual)`).

Answer (score 1):

With a little less regex and a little more `strsplit`:

```
mydf$transmission <- gsub("Auto(?=[^m])", "Automatic", mydf$transmission, perl=TRUE)
sapply(
  strsplit(gsub("[()-]", " ", mydf$transmission), "\\s+"),
  function(x) paste(x[1], paste0(x[-1],collapse="") )
)
#[1] "Automatic L3"                 "Automatic L4"                
#[3] "Automatic S4"                 "Automatic 6spd"              
#[5] "Automatic L3"                 "Automatic variablegearratios"
#[7] "Manual 4spd"
```